# Android - Send echo requests to all cell towers in range

Tags: android, telephony, gsm

Is this possible to do?

I want to ping or send some kind of echo request to all cell towers in range, and get back a timestamp and the id of each tower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be that there will only be one cell tower in range (or 2) at a time.  Cell companies are not going to spend the money to over-saturate an area.

Check out this article on Ericsson website. [GET CELL TOWER ID](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/create-simple-cell-id-look-application-android)